# 12.04 to 12.10 upgrade failure

Tags: boot, 12.10

In upgrading 12.04 to 12.10 via system upgrade when the system rebooted all I got was my desk-top without any command icons.  Now all my files are locked into 12.10 and no way to retrieve them.  I finally reinstalled 12.04 in a new partition but I don't have the knowledge on how to access 12.10 from it.  Being a newbie with Linux I feel like I have all thumbs.  I'd like to correct 12.10 but have to idea on what the problem is or how to access it.   HELP!!!

Video card is a PNY GeForce 4 MX440 8x on an intel motherboard, so fglrx is not the issue

Comment: May i ask? you say you reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 again and removed 12.10 what option u used to install 12,04 it waqs install together with 12.10 or completely remove 12.10 and make fresh install? Or you managed hard drive?

Comment: I didn't remove 12.10;  I repartitioned and loaded a fresh install of 12.04 along side.  When I originally upgraded to 12.10 I used 12.04's upgrade manager.

Comment: once i had problems upgrading to new release the were errors cause electricity turned off i fixed it with restore option in grub menu.I  enebled networking in restore options and fixed packages.It fixed all upgrade errors and did the rest. Also user can try sudo apt-get update -f and ,apt-get -f install.You can try to finish upgrade. Try sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop, sudo apt-get install reinstall unity , unity --replace and check if ubuntu unity plugin enabled in ccsm

Comment: I can't do any of that...I don't have any frames or sidebars when I attempt to load 12.10, just the empty desktop.

Comment: You can press hold shift at system startup right? For other commands  you can summon the console with cntrl+alt+f1 login and try  there..Or use terminal with cntrl+alt+t

Comment: also check in ccsm if unity plugin is enabled and remove fglrx drivers summon terminal by cntrl alt t and run sudo apt-get remove fglrx.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, your issue isn't with `fglrx` as `fglrx` is used by AMD/ATI GPUs. Your problem is caused by nVidia Drivers.

Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

```
    `$sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
    `$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates
    `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304
```

Or just open Synaptic and search for `nvidia`, delete everything that you see now.

Reboot the system. See if everything's working.
Run this command to check if Unity-3D will work:

`$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

Reboot again. Reinstall latest nVidia drivers:

`$sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`

Comment: Thanx, TomKat...I tried your solution and it exposed that it hadn't even loaded hte Nvidia files??  So I went straight to the install line and I was able to get my icons showing on the desktop but the sideboard and the top panel doesn't load at all.  In searching through terminal I discovered that it doesn't have Unity loaded either.  This was an upgrade through 12.04.  Is there anyway to clean up the program without losing all my files?

Comment: Hmmm... Clean up which 'program'? Run `unity` in terminal at once. If it doesn't run, I'd tell you how it can be installed.

Comment: "Hmmm... Clean up which 'program'?"  I meant the the entire 12.10 dist.  I did go into terminal and typed "Unity" (correct action?) which then proceeded to give me an entire list of operations all of which were removed because of, mainly, (the reasons given) "Error: Plugin 'open GL' not loaded." and GLK is missing on display ":0.0".  Haven't got the slightest idea what that means.

Comment: I guess you mean `GLX` missing. Which GPU drivers are you using? Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and `sudo apt-get purge fglrx`. Reboot and run `$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` See what happens.

Comment: The message I received was "Error: GLX is not available on the system."  After rebooting, the sidebar and top bar became visible and operational although as slow as cold molasses. Is this speed normal?  I hope not.  Are there any printouts I can post to give a clearer picture of the problem?

Comment: What's your CPU (make, model, clock-rate), RAM (type, size) & HDD (type, storage, size of `/`)?